# Alert Key Compromised, upgrade required

Tags: wallet-security

I just got this message: "Alert key compromised, upgrade required".
 How urgent is this? Am I in danger of losing my Bitcoin?
 What do I do?

Comment: Might be a scam to trick you into installing malware.  Be cautious.

Comment: No, it's not a scam.

Answer (score 10):

The network wide Alert system is being retired. **No Bitcoins are at risk and this warning may be safely ignored.** Upgrade to the newest version of your wallet software to no longer see the alert.

Read more [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2016-11-01-alert-retirement).